# Writing Express server on React project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server

I am new to React and I am trying to create a web which contains
the following pages:
1. Home
2. Services
   - service 1 
   - service 2
   - service 3
   - service 4
3. About
4. Contact
The server logic, have to contain logic about contact from that I have on contact page (for receiving a message from somebody and sending an auto message that says that message received) and logic for pages routing.
Basically on Home page, I am rendering images and text and I have some buttons that links to other pages.
On the Service page again I have some buttons that link to my services, text, and images.
All my services render only text and images. Same for About page.
On the contact page, I have a contact form for which I have written server logic.
Can anyone help me and tell me if the written server logic is correct and how can I test this logic. I tried to run: node server.js, but gives me "Error: Cannot find module '/Users/seldaali/Desktop/my-website/server.js' "

Here is my App.js:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>

    <Navbar />
   

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/services" component={Services} />
        <Route exact path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />

        <Route exact path="/services/service 1" component={service-1} />
        <Route exact path="/services/service 2" component={service-2} />
        <Route exact path="/services/service 3" component={service-3} />
        <Route exact path="/services/service 4" component={service-4}/>

        <Route component={Error} />
      </Switch>

    </>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Then my index.js:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

End my server.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var cors = require('cors');
var helmet = require('helmet');
const creds = require('./config');

var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(9000);

app.use(cors())
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/', router)

/* Pages routing */

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Home')
})

app.get('/services', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Services')
  console.log('services')
})
app.get('/services/service 1', function (req, res) {
  res.send('service 1')
})
app.get('/services/service 2', function (req, res) {
  res.send('service 2')
})
app.get('/services/service 3', function (req, res) {
  res.send('service 3')
})
app.get('/services/service 4', function (req, res) {
  res.send('service 4')
})
app.get('/about-us', function(req, res) {
  res.send('About us')
})
app.get('/contact', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Contact us')
})

app.use(express.static('images'));



var transport = {
    host: '', // replace with the SMTP host of your provider
    port: 25,
    auth: {
    user: creds.USER,
    pass: creds.PASS
  }
}

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport)

transporter.verify((error, success) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Server is ready to take messages');
  }
});

router.post('/send', (req, res, next) => {
  var name = req.body.name
  var email = req.body.email
  var phone = req.body.phone
  var message = req.body.message
  var content = `name: ${name} \n email: ${email} \n phone: ${phone} \n message: ${message} `

  var mail = {
    from: name,
    to: 'my email',  // Change to email address that you want to receive messages on
    subject: 'New Message from Contact Form',
    text: content
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        status: 'fail'
      })
    } else {
      res.json({
       status: 'success'
      })
      transporter.sendMail({
     from: "my email",
     to: email,
     subject: "Submission was successful",
     text: `Thank you for contacting us!\n\nForm details\nName: ${name}\n Email: ${email}\n Phone: ${phone}\n Message: ${message}`
   }, function(error, info){
     if(error) {
       console.log(error);
     } else{
       console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
     }
   });
    }
  })
})
```

My package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.22.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "random-unicode-emoji": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-sticky-header": "^0.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "react-scripts server"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different things i.e. `server` (express) & `client` (react). server returns data & client consumes that data but in your server i.e.

```
app.get('/services', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Services')
  console.log('services')
})
```

you are not returning data rather just sending a page. So either use pages sent from server or since you are using react for client then just return data like this:

```
app.get('/services', function (req, res) {
  console.log('services')
  return ['service data 1', 'service data 2', ...]
})
```

then in one of your components i.e. `Services` make a `get` request using an http library like `fetch` or `axios` to the route you defined i.e. `/services` that is now returning array that you can loop over through & render on client.

I am not react guy so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do i need some database configuration given the page content?

Comment: In your simple case you can create some dummy array & return that to client so don't need to have configure DB connection & queries etc.